# UIScrollView height not updated dynamically based on views size?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, constraints

I have VC, in that i added UIScrollView -> UIView. After that i added 3 tableViews and i added constraints. Based on content tableViews sized dynamically, for example tbl1, tbl2 and tbl3 has 10, 5 and 7 rows respectively. Based on content i want to update my entire view. Here **tableViews height** updated successfully but **not ScrollView**.

My Code is...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    tbl1.delegate = self
    tbl1.dataSource = self
    tbl2.delegate = self
    tbl2.dataSource = self
    tbl3.delegate = self
    tbl3.dataSource = self
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //Update tbl1 frame
        var frame = self.tbl1.frame
        frame.size.height = self.tbl1.contentSize.height
        self.tbl1.frame = frame
        //Update tbl2 frame
        var frame2 = self.tbl2.frame
        let y = self.tbl1.frame.maxY
        frame2.origin.y = y
        frame2.size.height = self.tbl2.contentSize.height
        self.tbl2.frame = frame2
        //Update tbl3 frame
        var frame3 = self.tbl3.frame
        let y2 = self.tbl2.frame.maxY
        frame3.origin.y = y2
        frame3.size.height = self.tbl3.contentSize.height
        self.tbl3.frame = frame3
    }

}

// MARK: - UITableView Delegates
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == tbl1 {
        return 10
    } else if tableView == tbl2 {
        return 5
    } else {
        return 7
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == tbl1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "TBL ONE"

        return cell
    } else if tableView == tbl2 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "TBL TWO"

        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "TBL THREE"

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: where you update your scrollview height?

Comment: Show the constraints you added to the `scrollView`.

Comment: Actually I'm not updated scrollview, because of I added constraints last tableview bottom to scrollView

Comment: @PGDev First I added ScrollView Cons:0,0,0,0. I added view on scrollView Cons:0,0,0,0 and width equals to main view and height equals to main view. After that I added tableViews tbl1 cons: 0,0,0, height 125. Tbl2 Cons: 0,0,0, height 125. tbl3 cons : 0,0,0,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this line to end of your `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

```
self.scrollView.contentSize.height = self.tbl1.contentSize.height + self.tbl2.contentSize.height + self.tbl3.contentSize.height
```

Comment: What is this subviews.last!  in self.myScrollView.subviews[0].subviews.last!

Comment: i put a comment you can set your tableview3 or check that subview is equal to tableview3

Comment: I copied your code and I called that(setScrollViewContentSize()) function in viewDidLayoutSubviews(). But scrollView not updated

Comment: I'm getting setting scroll height: 212.0

Comment: i think your storyboard constraint is not proper

Comment: First I added ScrollView Cons:0,0,0,0. I added view on scrollView Cons:0,0,0,0 and width equals to main view and height equals to main view.

Comment: After that I added tableViews tbl1 cons: 0,0,0, height 125. Tbl2 Cons: 0,0,0, height 125. tbl3 cons : 0,0,0,0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182914/discussion-between-ios-and-pushp).